# How to get all the text box id of last row of add/remove table in html

Tags: javascript, html, database

How to get all the text box id of last row of add/remove table in html java script ...

I want to delete my last row from the html table and database.. so how can I get the id of last row...
Please help me with the code snippet?

```
function remvmain(i) {
    var table = document.getElementById("1.1.2");
        $('#1.1.2 tr:last').find('input:text').each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id') );  
    });

    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr').length;

    alert(rows-1);
    i=i-1;
    var n=i*5;
    if( i > 1 ) {
        rows = rows - 1;
        var row = table.deleteRow(rows);
        rows = rows - 1;
        row = table.rows[rows];
        var m=n/5;
        var type=document.getElementById("fullname"+n);
        if(type == null){
            var x = row.insertCell(4);
            x.innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:void(0);' id='addNew' onclick='addmain("+m+")'><img style='padding-left: 12px;' src='./images/Plus.png' /></a>  <a href='javascript:void(0);' id='remNew' onclick='remvmain("+m+")'><img style='padding-left: 12px;'  src='./images/close.png'/></a>";
        } else {
            var val = parseInt(document.getElementById("fullname"+n).value);
            var member = document.getElementById("families").value;
            var last2 = member.slice(-2);
            var secondary = parseInt(document.getElementById("family"));
            rows=rows-val-1;
            row = table.rows[rows];
            var x = row.insertCell(4);
            flag=1;
            x.innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:void(0);' id='addNew' onclick='addmain("+m+")'><img style='padding-left: 12px;' src='./images/Plus.png' /></a>  <a href='javascript:void(0);' id='remNew' onclick='remvmain("+m+")'><img style='padding-left: 12px;'  'src='./images/close.png' /></a>";
        }
    } else {
        rows = rows - 1;
        var row = table.deleteRow(rows);
        rows = rows - 1;
        row = table.rows[rows];
        var x = row.insertCell(4);
        x.innerHTML="<a href='javascript:void(0);' id='addNew' onclick='addmain("+i+")'><img style='padding-left: 12px;' src='./images/Plus.png'/></a>";
    }
        document.getElementById("maincount").value=i;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: This will depend on the table HTML, currently you have just pasted a load of JavaScript with no context or problem description whatsoever.

Comment: Handy to have the html table as well here